# Image scaling inside a canvas

Tags: image, math, transformation

Let's assume we have a container with the size of 500 x 300 (w x h).
Inside this container we have a canvas with the same size, but with a different reference system inside it, with the size of 700 x 1000.

When I put an image of 700 x 1000 in this canvas it will obviously appear distorted, because the canvas occupies the entire 500 x 300 pixels of its parent container - even if inside it is still 700 x 1000.

Now, I am trying to figure out a formula to scale the image in the interlal reference system so the image doesn't appear distorted then loaded in the canvas.

Can anybody help?

Comment: It would be great if you said what ratio your coordinate systems have to the real sizes. I mean, is it true, for example, that 500 / real_container_width = 300 / real_container_height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have w = 700, h = 1000, i.e. w_container / w_canvas  = 5/7 != h_container / h_canvas = 3/10, you will not be able to load you image not being distorted and taking entire space of the container. I just can tell you how to resize your image properly.

To save the width-height ratio of your image (equals 7/10, I think this is what you mean under "distorted image") you should calculate how your image's ratio rescales after putting the image on the canvas. 
canvas_ratio(7/10) * x = container_ratio(5/3), hence x = 50/21. So if your image has the ratio y, then it will become y*x = y*50/21.

So you should just resize your image before putting it on the canvas such a way that after multiplying this ratio by x it would be 7/10 (the ratio when your image looks perfect). We have an equation y*50/21 = 7/10, hence **y = 147/500**. That's the ratio your image should have! 
For example, you can make image size 294x1000, and after putting it to the canvas it will have height of 300 pixels in your container's coordinate system and 294*(500/700) = 210 pixel width (unfortunately, not 500). Hope this will be useful information for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that's what I need indeed, to save the width-height of the image. Doing some calculations by hand I too have find out that the resulting width in the container's reference should be 210, I was just unable to create the formulas. I will try your answer - probably tomorrow - and let you know if/how it worked. Thx!

Comment: (my purpose is to fit images of any size inside a given container, so it's ok if the image won't fit 100% of the container's width or height - as long as it keeps it's ratio)

Comment: I have tried to adapt your calculations for all 4 cases (box/image  is horizontal/vertical) and it works. So ty!